Complex valued integral
I'm trying to evaluate the integral $$\int\limits_{-R}^R\frac{e^{ipt}}{1+t^2}dt$$ where $R\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p\in\mathbb{C}$. My actual goal is to show that for $R\to\infty$ this integral evaluates to $\pi e^{-p}$. I've decomposed it into partial fractions and shown that it can be expressed as$$-\frac{ie^p}{2}\int\limits_\alpha\frac{e^t}{t}dt+\frac{ie^{-p}}{2}\int\limits_\beta\frac{e^t}{t}dt$$where $\alpha$ is a straight path from $-Rpi-p$ to $Rpi-p$ and $\beta$ is a straight path from $-Rpi+p$ to $Rpi+p$, but seem to be stuck here too, as this integral has no analytic solution. Any help?

If $p$ is real and $R=\infty$, we recognize the Fourier tranform of the Cauchy function, which is proportional to $e^{-k |p|}$ for a certain constant $k$.

@FelixMarin no need to use the real part function. As I explain $p$ must be limited to real numbers if the integral is to converge at all.

@OscarLanzi Yes. I was blind about it. Thanks.

First off, check your domain. You can't allow any nonzero imaginary part of $p$ or else the integrand grows exponentially as $t\to+\infty$ or as $t\to-\infty$, and then the integral diverges. So we we should limit $p$ to $\in\mathbb{R}$. A corrollary is that the function need be defined only for real $p$.
With $p=0$ the integral evaluates to $\pi$ via elementary means. With $p$ forced real we then consider each possible sign as a separate case. For $p>0$ close the integration path with a semicircle through the upper half-plane, giving a contour over which the integral is evaluated with the Residue Theorem. There is only one contained pole which is simple, and you can show that the semicircular component vanishes as $R\to\infty$.
For $p<0$ the closure would have to go through the lower half-plane. The contour is then clockwise, so you need to reverse the sign of the Residue Theorem result.
You will not get $\pi\exp(-p)$ for all real $p$. You will need to modify the $-p$ part in a way I will let you uncover.
